# how to show calendar in nginput[date] when click the input

Tags: angularjs

I have a date input like this:

```
<input type="date" name="input" ng-model="date" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" class="form-control"/>
```

Now I want show calendar when click the input. How to controller the date calendar?

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="date">` is implemented on the level of the browser. I use Chrome and I do see datetime field.

[image]

Comment: I mean click the input but not the button